# Specifying a directory path as a command line parameter in python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

I`m having a problem specifying a path as a command line parameter. I am running on Windows.

Code:

```
import sys
import os

startPath = sys.argv[1]
print startPath
print os.path.dirname(startPath)
```

Command line parameter:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\python scripts\New folder
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\python scripts\New folder

C:\Users\username\Documents\python scripts
```

My Problem:

So, the last part of the path (`\New folder`) is being lost in the directory name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the command line parameter, i.e. the path, in double quotes:

```
python myscript.py "C:\Users\username\Documents\python scripts\New folder"
```

Comment: Without quotes the output would be `C:\Users\username\Documents\python` and `C:\Users\username\Documents`.

Answer (score 2):

You should input the trailing `\`, or add it in your code if it is not present. Otherwise `os.path.dirname` treats `New folder` as a file name.

Comment: I suppose this does what XYZ wants, but if the argument is the path to a directory, there's no reason to use `os.path.dirname`, and requiring a trailing slash is fragile. Just normalize it as a fully qualified path using `os.path.abspath` and verify that it's a directory using `os.path.isdir`.